# JSON Object Tree HTML View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Hi I've tried a lot of ways but seems to that I cannot get it, I have below json obj how can I display it as a tree HTML view with ul li items using JavaScript ?

```
[
  {
    "CategoriesModelId": 7,
    "Name": "Parnet",
    "Parent": null,
    "ParentId": null,
    "Order": 0,
    "Children": [
      {
        "CategoriesModelId": 8,
        "Name": "Child 1",
        "Parent": null,
        "ParentId": null,
        "Order": 0,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "CategoriesModelId": 9,
        "Name": "Chil 2 ",
        "Parent": null,
        "ParentId": null,
        "Order": 0,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "CategoriesModelId": 10,
        "Name": "Razvan ",
        "Parent": null,
        "ParentId": null,
        "Order": 0,
        "Children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There are really millions of answers online for this question, lots of them around this website too! Try to google "json object to html list" for example ;)

Comment: Thank you for answer, this might make me look stupid, it seems that even I've search a lot did not manage to find an example which works for me

Comment: No problem, you will find the answer around here, I'm pretty sure, just be sure what are you looking for! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is how I've managed to do it, finally

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "CategoriesModelId": 7,
    "Nume": "parent",
    "Parent": null,
    "ParentId": null,
    "Order": 0,
    "Children": [
      {
        "CategoriesModelId": 0,
        "Nume": "Child",
        "Parent": null,
        "ParentId": null,
        "Order": 0,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "CategoriesModelId": 0,
        "Nume": "Child",
        "Parent": null,
        "ParentId": null,
        "Order": 0,
        "Children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CategoriesModelId": 12,
    "Nume": "Parent 2",
    "Parent": null,
    "ParentId": null,
    "Order": 0,
    "Children": []
  }
]

var html = [];

function createList(arr) {
    html.push('<ul>');
    $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
        html.push('<li>' + val.Nume);
        if (val.Children) {
            createList(val.Children)
           
        }
        html.push('</li>');
    });
    html.push('</ul>');
}
createList(obj)
$('body').append(html.join(''))
```

```css
ul{ border: 1px solid green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```